# How to set primary key in table using googledatastore.?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

hi i have one doubt.How to set primary key in table using googledatastore.

Answer (score 1):

```
@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;
```

Documentation can be found [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Creating_and_Using_Keys).